# how to invoke a function from server frequently?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to create a function which is it will running every month on a specific date,
how can I do this?

anyone can help me?

Answer (score 4):

Normally by using some task scheduling software such as Windows Task Schedular or (for anything that isn't Windows) [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).

Comment: is it working in a web hosting server?

Comment: That depends on the hosting service. Anything quarter-decent will support something along those lines.